# Rank function to see value appearing more than 1 SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I needed some advice and help as I am trying to experiment in `SQL SERVER` with an appropriate Rank function.

Basically, what I want to do is to count how many times a contract agreement is repeated in the data. In `Excel`, I used `Count(A:A;A2)`

```
Cust_Nr    Contract Agreement Nr
5639232    19243062
10072067   3316516
10072067   3316516
5639232    19243062
20095770   49940680
10072067   3316516
```

My question is, is there a way of using Rank of Rank Dense function to figure out how many times a `contract agreement Nr` appears more than once? For example, the `contract agreement nr:3316516` appears twice. I would want a another column that shows this :

```
Cust_Nr    Contract Agreement Nr  Duplicate
5639232    19243062
10072067   3316516                3
10072067   3316516                3
5639232    19243062
20095770   49940680
10072067   3316516                3
```

So `contract agreement nr 3316516` appears in total 3 times in the data.

How can I do this?

Comment: What about other rows that are not 3?

Comment: Are you sure you want `RANK` and not, say `COUNT`? Because it sounds like you want `COUNT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this, no need for ranks:

```
select *, count(*) over (partition by [Contract Agreement Nr]) as RowsPerContractNumber
from MyTable
```

Edit: if you want the non-duplicate rows to be blank, use this:

```
select *
, case count(*) over (partition by [Contract Agreement Nr]) 
    when 1 then ''
    else cast(count(*) over (partition by [Contract Agreement Nr]) as varchar)
end
as RowsPerContractNumber
from MyTable
```

Comment: Thank you. I have now learnt to use excel's Countif in SQL SERVER too. :=) Thank you!